# possible to only allow users on my chromebook to only surf a handful of sites?

Tags: router, firewall, whitelist, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm looking and i can't find it.

Possible to configure a chromebook to allow users access to ONLY a handful of domains like gmail, google, youtube, linkedin, etc? not deny but allow only...  if so, where/how? version specific? Any hacks or work around?

If not, any good comcast fiber internet compatible wifi routers out there with built in firewall that can do this well.. maybe by mac addresses? that log?  and can chromebook users hack/change their mac address without rooting to hack around this restriction?  Can Windows 10 users hack their way around this?

Answer (score 0):

To set policies for the Chromebook itself you'd need to enroll it on an Enterprise domain:

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1360534?hl=en

I assume you're not an admin for such a domain however. If you want set policies for your kids you can use parental controls on their Google Accounts:

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7680868?hl=en

You can also control which accounts are allowed on your Chromebook:

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1059252?hl=en